# Variable substitution in a configuration file

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Variable substitution in Gitlab only seem to work inside the `gitlab-ci.yml` file.

However I have a configuration file (k8s secret) where I would like to set different values depending if I'm in a staging or a production environment.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: tls-config
  namespace: myNamespace
type: kubernetes.io/tls
data:
  tls.crt: |
    ${TLS_CRT}

  tls.key: |
    ${TLS_KEY}
```

Where **TLS_CRT** & **TLS_KEY** would be variables defined in /settings/ci_cd/variables.

How should one handle variable substitution in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an editor like `sed`

For example, if you had the file like:

```yaml
data:
  tls.crt: |
    #TLS_CRT#

  tls.key: |
    #TLS_KEY#
```

You could use `sed` like this as part of your GitLab job to replace its contents:

```yaml
myjob:
  script:
  - sed -i "s|#TLS_CRT#|${TLS_CRT}|" ./path/to/file
  - sed -i "s|#TLS_KEY#|${TLS_KEY}|" ./path/to/file
```

Then the file contents will be something like this:

```
data:
  tls.crt: |
        MIIC2DCCAcCgAwIBAgIBATANBgkqh ...
  tls.key: |
        MIIEpgIBAAKCAQEA7yn3bRHQ5FHMQ ...
```

Using the pattern `#word#` is not totally necessary. However, it does make using the `sed` easier, as it avoids needing to escape the literal `${}` characters in the shell command.

As a short explanation of the sed command used here:

```
#    v shorthand for --in-place; edits the file directly
sed -i "s|FIRST_ARGUMENT|SECOND_ARGUMENT|" ./path/to/file
#         ^ replace this ^ with this       ^ in this file
```

Fore more info, see here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/112024/453397